# Indent long line stdout

Tags: bash, awk, sed, stdout, interactive

Let's say I have a standard 80 columns terminal, execute command with long line output (i.e. stdout from `ls`) that splits into two or more lines, and want to indent the continuation line of all my bash stdout.

Indent should be configurable, 1 or 2 or 3 or whatever spaces.

from this

`lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          24 Feb 19  1970 sdcard -> /storage/emula`
`ted/legacy/`

to this

`lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          24 Feb 19  1970 sdcard -> /storage/emula`
  `ted/legacy/`

Read this [Indenting multi-line output in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484774/indenting-multi-line-output-in-a-shell-script) so I tried to pipe `| sed 's/^/  /'` but gives me the exact opposite, indents the first lines and not the continuation.

Ideally I would put a script in profile.rc or whatever so every time I open an interactive shell and execute any command long output gets indented .

Comment: `awk` would seem to be the easiest way of doing this - consider adding that tag. You could pick up the width of the terminal with `tput cols` and filter with an `awk` script like `awk w=$(tput cols) 'length($0)>w{print substr($0,1,w);print "____",substr($0,w+1);next}1'` Then put that in a `bash` function for ease of use.

Comment: Just pipe the output to ```column -t```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this.

```
awk -v width="$COLUMNS" -v spaces=4 '
BEGIN {
  pad = sprintf("%*s", spaces, "") # generate `spaces` spaces
}
NF {                               # if current line is not empty
  while (length > width) {         # while length of current line is greater than `width`
    print substr($0, 1, width)     # print `width` chars from the beginning of it
    $0 = pad substr($0, width + 1) # and leave `pad` + remaining chars
  }
  if ($0 != "")                    # if there are remaining chars
    print                          # print them too 
  next
} 1' file
```

In one line:

```
awk -v w="$COLUMNS" -v s=4 'BEGIN{p=sprintf("%*s",s,"")} NF{while(length>w){print substr($0,1,w);$0=p substr($0,w+1)} if($0!="") print;next} 1'
```

As @Mark suggested in comments, you can put this in a function and add it to `.bashrc` for ease of use.

```
function wrap() {
  awk -v w="$COLUMNS" -v s=4 'BEGIN{p=sprintf("%*s",s,"")} NF{while(length>w){print substr($0,1,w);$0=p substr($0,w+1)} if($0!="") print;next} 1'
}
```

Usage:

```
ls -l | wrap
```

---

Edit by Ed Morton per request:

Very similar to oguzismails script above but should work with Busybox or any other awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { pad = sprintf("%" spaces "s","") }
{
    while ( length($0) > width ) {
        printf "%s", substr($0,1,width)
        $0 = substr($0,width+1)
        if ( $0 != "" ) {
            print ""
            $0 = pad $0
        }
    }
    print
}
$
$ echo '123456789012345678901234567890' | awk -v spaces=3 -v width=30 -f tst.awk
123456789012345678901234567890
$ echo '123456789012345678901234567890' | awk -v spaces=3 -v width=15 -f tst.awk
123456789012345
   678901234567
   890
$ echo '' | awk -v spaces=3 -v width=15 -f tst.awk

$
```

That first test case is to show that you don't get a blank line printed after a full-width input line and the third  is to show that it doesn't delete blank rows. Normally I'd have used `sprintf("%*s",spaces,"")` to create the `pad` string but I see in a comment that that doesn't work in the apparently non-POSIX awk you're using.

Comment: As bash was tagged, you could probably: `awk -v width=$COLUMNS ...`?

Comment: I'm getting Unexpected token, Android 4.4 busybox 1.30.1

Comment: @JuTutt if it's an option install a POSIX compliant awk. Otherwise see Ed Morton's edit on my answer.

Comment: tried to make it in a one line function but no luck`awk -v spaces=3 -v width=80 'BEGIN{pad=sprintf("%",spaces,"s","")} {while(length($0)>width){printf "%s",substr($0,1,width);$0=substr($0,width+1)};if($0!=""){print "" $0=pad $0}print}'`

Comment: also made an alias in .bashrc `alias ll='ls -Al | wrap'`, works with first @oguzismail, is there a way to append this wrap function to all commands without making an alias for everyone?

Comment: @JuTutt that's whole another question

Comment: @JuTutt It doesn't have to be a one liner but here it is anyways: `awk -v spaces=4 -v width=10 'BEGIN{pad=sprintf("%"spaces"s","")}{while(length($0)>width){printf "%s",substr($0,1,width);$0=substr($0,width+1);if($0!=""){print "";$0=pad $0}};print}'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/./&\n  /80;P;D' file
```

This splits lines into length 80 and indents the following line(s) by 2 spaces.

Or if you prefer:

```
s='  ' c=80
sed "s/./&\n$s/$c;P;D" file
```

To prevent empty lines being printed, use:

```
sed 's/./&\n/80;s/\n$//;s/\n    /;P;D' file
```

or more easily:

```
sed 's/./\n    &/81;P;D' file
```

Comment: That would delete empty lines or lines of all blank chars. You're missing a `'` at the end of the first script btw.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using pure bash string manipulation.
You can make the script to read `stdin` and format whatever it read.

```
MAX_LEN=5  # length of the first/longest line
IND_LEN=2  # number of indentation spaces
short_len="$((MAX_LEN-IND_LEN))"
while read line; do
    printf "${line:0:$MAX_LEN}\n"
    for i in $(seq $MAX_LEN $short_len ${#line}); do
        printf "%*s${line:$i:$short_len}\n" $IND_LEN
    done
done
```

Usage: (assuming the script is saved as `indent.sh`)

```
$ echo '0123456789' | ./indent.sh
01234
  567
  89
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for some of the reasons not to do this (including it will be extremely slow, will corrupt the text, can produce cryptic syntax errors, will behave different depending on the contents of the directory where you run it, and has security issues).

Comment: Some specific comments: Use lower case or mixed case variable names to avoid the risk of colliding with environment or shell variable names. Don't use `seq` unless you have to. Use C-style `for` loops instead: `for ((i=max_len; i<=${#line}; i+=ind_len))`. Don't put variables in the format argument of `printf`: `printf '%*s%s\n' "$ind_len" '' "${line:$i:$short_len}"` You can do math this way: `(( short_len = max_len - ind_len ))` which I find cleaner looking.